# Zend Cache file

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, helper

I'm using **Doctrine 1.2** with **Zend Framework 1** .

I have a lot of controllers and I have left sidebar  and right sidebar inside my layout, and I have visitors and authentication users within active session .

I have done a basic caching method like :

```
$frontend= array('lifetime' => 3600);

$backend= array('cache_dir' => '/data/cache/FileName');

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('core', 'File', $frontend, $backend);

if ((!$result = $cache->load('fileName'))) {
    /* my code here*/
    $cache->save($page, 'fileName');
} else {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->getResponse()->appendBody($result);
}
```

But every time I need to cash page in controllers I repeat this code in every controller so I would like to create helper to manage my cash for all cases and scenarios with set of parameters like (file Name, life time, is log in user, other) and cashing files from layout like left sidebar and able to delete cash files .
so I call methods only from my controllers and handle it from one place .

What is the best way to build this caching technique helper in Zend framework and if you have any
examples please help me and provide me with best way to build it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page**  and start your the caching in your zend **bootstrap.php**.

like :

```
 $frontendOptions = array(
                    'lifetime' => '604800000',
                    'content_type_memorization' => false,
                    'default_options' => array(
                        'cache' => true,
                        'make_id_with_cookie_variables' => false,
                        'make_id_with_session_variables' => false,
                        'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
                        'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
                        'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
                        'cache_with_files_variables' => true,
                        'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
                    ),
                    'regexps' => array(
                        '$' => array('cache' => true),
                    )
                );

                $backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => $yourDirectoryPath);
                $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
                $cache->start();
```

Follow the tutorial from Zend Cache manual

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.theory.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to cache the pages, why not just cache the expensive data?

In Zend Framework 1, plugins are loaded on every controller,[ZF1 Custom Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

or use Action helpers in only in certain places [ZF1 Action Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)